# How do i fix success is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following error in my console
Uncaught TypeError: success is not a function

The error gets caught in Chrome browser console here:
**success();**

I figured success is not properly defined or is in the wrong area. The following JavaScript that I'm using is:

```
            if (jQuery === undefined) { // This ensures that jQuery is loaded before running document ready code:
              getScript('/imagesrv/apps/common/js/jq/jquery-1.8.3.min.js', function() {
                if (jQuery === undefined) { // Super failsafe - still somehow failed...
                  bindAllHandlers();
                } else {
                  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    gpUtilsDocReady();
                  });
                }
              });
            } else { // jQuery was already loaded
              $(document).ready(function(){
                gpUtilsDocReady();
              });
            }

            function gpUtilsDocReady() {
              $('div.headingarea').off('click').on('click', function() {
                $(this).closest('div.analystgroup').find('div.expandblock').toggle('normal');
                $(this).closest('div.headingarea').toggleClass('boldText');
                $(this).closest('div.headingarea').find('div.arrowdown').toggleClass('arrowright','arrowdown');
              });
              $("div.expandblock:first").show();    
              $("div.arrowdown:first").toggleClass('arrowright','arrowdown');
              $("div.headingarea:first").toggleClass('boldText');
            }

            function getScript(url, success) {
              var script = document.createElement('script');
              script.src = url;
              var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0], done = false;

              script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() { // Attach handlers for all browsers
                if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                  done = true;
                  success();
                  script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                  head.removeChild(script);
                };
              };
              head.appendChild(script);
            }

            function PTHTTPGETRequest_Replacement(url, functionOrDiv) {
            if (arguments.length == 1) {
                     $.ajax(url);
                  }
                  else if (eval("typeof " + functionOrDiv + " == 'function'")) {
                     $.ajax(url).complete(window[functionOrDiv] );
                  }
                  else {
                     $("#" + functionOrDiv).load(url, helpCallback(functionOrDiv));
                  }
               }

            //popup window functions
            function rawPopUp(url, width, height, features, target) {
            // attempt to clean up all random js popups
            var u = url;
            var t = target;
            var w = width;
            var h = height;
            var f = features;

            // return if there is no URL
            if (u == null) {
            return false;
            }

            // set up default values if none passed
            t = t ? t : "_blank";
            w = w ? w : 990;
            h = h ? h : 650;
            f = f ? f : "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes";

            // find middle x and y position of the screen
            var left = (window.screen.width - w)/2;
            var top  = (window.screen.height - h)/2;
            var newWin=null;
            var settings = 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',top=' + top + ',left=' + left + ', ' + f;
            newWin = window.open(u, t, settings);
            newWin.focus();
            return(newWin);
            }

            function openBio(href) {
            // opens Analysts Bio
            rawPopUp(href, '579', '450', 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes','_0');
            return false;
            }

            var contentPopupInProgressMap = {};

            /*
             * containerId - The unique id of the popup container div.  It must also
             *               contain a div with the id of <containerId>_content where
             *               the html content will be loaded.  The entire container will
             *               be shown/hidden. 
             * uniqueId - An id that is unique to the page for identifying the popup.
             * html - The html to display.
             * url - The query url for the html to display.
             * minDelayMs - The minimum delay until the popup is shown (hovering)
             *
             * Positioning is handled by the following pairs (if not supplied, 
             * the popup will not be positioned):
             *    absLeft/absCenter: Either the absolute left or center for the popup.
             *    absTop/absMiddle: Either the absolute top or middle for the popup.
             */
            function showContentPopup(args) {
               args = args || {};
               var uniqueId = args.uniqueId;
               // Clear the popup delay for this source from the map.
               delete contentPopupInProgressMap[uniqueId];
               var container = $('#' + args.containerId);      
               if (container) {
                  var popupInfo = jQuery.extend(true, {}, args);
                  delete popupInfo["html"];
                  delete popupInfo["url" ];
                  popupInfo.startTime = new Date().getTime();
                  // Add it to the inProgress map.
                  contentPopupInProgressMap[uniqueId]=popupInfo;

                  if ('html' in args && args.html) {
                     $('#' + popupInfo.containerId + '_content').html(args.html);
                     var minDelayMs = ('minDelayMs' in args && args.minDelayMs) ? args.minDelayMs : 0; 
                     setTimeout("eval(" + "showContentPopup_callback('" + uniqueId + "')" + ")", minDelayMs);
                  }
                  else if ('url' in args && args.url) {
                     $.ajax({
                        url: args.url,
                        success: function(html) {
                           if(html) {
                              $('#' + popupInfo.containerId + '_content').html(html);
                              var minDelayMs = ('minDelayMs' in args && args.minDelayMs) ? args.minDelayMs : 0;
                              minDelayMs = Math.max((minDelayMs - (new Date().getTime() -  popupInfo.startTime)), 0);
                              setTimeout("eval(" + "showContentPopup_callback('" + uniqueId + "')" + ")", minDelayMs);
                           }
                        }
                     });
                  }
               }
            }

            function hideContentPopup(uniqueId) {
               // Clear the delay.
               var popupInfo = contentPopupInProgressMap[uniqueId];
               if (popupInfo) {
                  $('#' + popupInfo.containerId).css('visibility', 'hidden');
               }
               delete contentPopupInProgressMap[uniqueId];
            }

            function showContentPopup_callback(uniqueId) {
               // Show the popup if in progress.
               var popupInfo = contentPopupInProgressMap[uniqueId];
               if (popupInfo && !popupInfo.visibile) {
                  var container = $('#' + popupInfo.containerId);      
                  if ('absCenter' in popupInfo && popupInfo.absCenter> 0) {
                     // Always keep the top edge of the container in view. 
                     container.offset({ left: Math.max(popupInfo.absCenter - (container.width()/2), 2) });
                  }         
                  else if ('absLeft' in popupInfo && popupInfo.absLeft >= 0) {
                     container.offset({ left: popupInfo.absLeft });
                  }

                  if ('absMiddle' in popupInfo && popupInfo.absMiddle > 0) {
                     // Always keep the left edge of the container in view. 
                     container.offset({ top: Math.max(popupInfo.absMiddle - (container.height()/2), $(window).scrollTop()  + 2) });
                  }         
                  else if ('absTop' in popupInfo && popupInfo.absTop >= 0) {
                     container.offset({ top: popupInfo.absTop });
                  }
                  container.css('visibility', 'visible');
                  popupInfo.visibile = true;
               }
            }

            function submitSearch(formName, location) {
                  rForm = eval('document.' + formName);
                  typeaheadTermType = document.getElementById("typeaheadTermType").value;
                  typeaheadTermId = document.getElementById("typeaheadTermId").value;
                  rForm.keywords.value = document.getElementById("keywords").value;

                  if (typeaheadTermType) {
                    if (typeaheadTermType.toLowerCase() == 'title') {
                       document.getElementById("typeaheadTermType").value = '';
                       document.getElementById("typeaheadTermId").value = '';
                       rForm.keywords.value = escape(document.getElementById("keywords").value);
                       window.location = documentdisplayurl + typeaheadTermId;
                       return false;
                     }
                  }

                  if (isValidKeyword(rForm.keywords.value)) {
                      rForm.submit();
                      return false;
                  }else if (isEmptyKeyword(rForm.keywords.value)) {
                      alert("Please provide keywords for your search");
                      return false;
                  } else {
                      alert("Your search is too general. Please provide keywords for your search.");
                      return false;
                  }
                }

            function isValidKeyword(keywords) {
                if (keywords.match(/[A-Z]+/g) ||
                    keywords.match(/[a-z]+/g) ||
                    keywords.match(/[0-9]+/g)) {
                    return true;
                }
                if(keywords == "" || keywords == null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }


            function isEmpty(control) {
                var s = control.value;
                // Trim leading whitespace.
                s = s.replace(/^\s+/g, '');
                return (s.length == 0);
            }


            function isEmptyKeyword(keywords) {
                if (keywords.match(/^ *$/)) {
                    return true;
                }
                if(keywords == "" || keywords == null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            <!-- Searchbox autocomplete-related functionality -->
            function getkey(e) {
                if (window.event)
                   return window.event.keyCode;
                else if (e)
                   return e.which;
                else
                   return null;
            }
            <!-- The submitSearch function must be implemented in the containing page. -->
            function searchboxKeyPress(e, formName, location){
                if (getkey(e)==13){
                    submitSearch(formName, location);
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if (window.hdrSearchBox_InitTypeAheadSearch2) {
                   function autocompleteCallbackSearchResults(searchboxName) {
                        var location = searchboxName.replace('/keywords/',''); 
                        submitSearch('gSearchForm', location)   
                    }

                    //typeaheadsugurl is defined in header.ftl for search
                    dojo.addOnLoad(function() { hdrSearchBox_InitTypeAheadSearch(typeaheadsugurl,'gSearchForm', 'keywords', 'divSearchSuggestionsSearchResults', 'autocompleteCallbackSearchResults', 10); });
            }

            function hdrSearchBox_InitTypeAheadSearch(typeaheadLink, formName, searchboxName, suggestionsDivName, callbackFunctionName, numResults) {
               //alert("personalized search:"+personalizedSearch);
               var minChars = 3;
               // Define an event handler to populate a hidden form field 
               // when an item gets selected 
               var typeaheadTermType = YAHOO.util.Dom.get("typeaheadTermType"); 
               var typeaheadTermId = YAHOO.util.Dom.get("typeaheadTermId"); 

               initTypeAheadSearch(
                  { formName: formName, 
                    searchboxName: searchboxName, 
                    suggestionsDivName: suggestionsDivName,
                    minQueryLength : minChars,

                    url:  typeaheadLink + '?num=' + numResults + '&minChars=' + minChars + '&keywords=',
                    requestSchema: {
                                     resultsList : "suggestions", 
                                     fields : [
                                         { key: "term" },
                                         { key: "count" },
                                         { key: "separator" },
                                         { key: "id" },
                                         { key: "type" }
                                     ]
                    }, 
                    formatResultFunction : function(oResultData, sQuery, sResultMatch) {
                        document.getElementById("divSearchHistoryResults").innerHTML = '';
                       // Cast to Strings. 
                       sQuery = String(sQuery);
                       // Preserve only alphanumerics, spaces, and the - symbol.
                        sQuery = sQuery.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]|^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
                       // Collapse all duplicate spaces.
                       sQuery = sQuery.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

                       var displayItem = String(oResultData.term);
                       var type = String(oResultData.type);
                       var idx = displayItem.toLowerCase().indexOf(sQuery.toLowerCase());
                       var pre = (idx> -1) ? displayItem.substr(0, idx) : '';
                       var sel = (idx> -1) ? displayItem.substr(idx, sQuery.length) : '';
                       var post = (idx> -1) ? displayItem.substr(idx + sQuery.length): displayItem;
                       var aMarkup = [''];
                        if( oResultData.separator && type != 'term') {
                           var header = "";
                           if (type == 'title') {
                              header = "Titles";
                           }
                           else if (type == 'analyst') {
                              header = "Analysts";
                           }
                           else if (type == 'vendor') {
                              header = "Vendors";
                           }
                           else if (type == 'term') {
                              header = "Keywords";
                           }
                           aMarkup = ['<div class=\"clusterTitle\"> <span class="TypeAheadBold">' + header + '</span></div><ul class=\"smartClusters\"><div class=\"TypeAheadWitdh\">',
                                          pre,
                                          '<span class="TypeAheadBold">',
                                          sel,
                                          '</span>',
                                          post,
                                       '</div></ul>'];
                        }
                        else {
                            aMarkup = ['<div class="TypeAheadWitdh">',
                                           pre,
                                           '<span class="TypeAheadBold">',
                                           sel,
                                           '</span>',
                                           post,
                                           '</div>'];
                        }
                       return (aMarkup.join(''));
                    },
                    itemSelectEventFunction:function(sType, aArgs ) {   
                        var myAC = aArgs[0]; // reference back to the AC instance 
                        var elLI = aArgs[1]; // reference to the selected LI element 
                        var oData = aArgs[2]; // object literal of selected item's result data 
                        // update hidden form fields with the selected item's id and type 
                        typeaheadTermId.value = oData.id;
                        typeaheadTermType.value = oData.type;
                     // Disable autocomplete.
                     eval(searchboxName + 'Enabled' + '=false;');
                     // Set a timeout to re-enable the typeahead. 
                     setTimeout(searchboxName + "Enabled=true", 3000);
                     // Execute the callback.
                        eval(callbackFunctionName + "('" + searchboxName + "')");
                  },
                    callbackFunction : callbackFunctionName,
                    // Turn off local cache.
                    queryMatchSubset : false,
                    maxResults: numResults });
            }

                // Basic type ahead configuration.
            function initTypeAheadSearch(oArgs) {
                // Create a var to track autocomplete enabled/disabled. 
                eval(oArgs.searchboxName + 'Enabled' + '=true');

                function autocompleteIsDisbabled() {
                    return eval(oArgs.searchboxName + 'Enabled' + '==false');
                }

                // Trap form submit for the form containing the autocomplete.
                YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(
                    YAHOO.util.Dom.get(oArgs.formName), 
                    "submit",
                   function(e, myForm) {
                        YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(e);
                        // Disable autocomplete.
                        eval(oArgs.searchboxName + 'Enabled' + '=false;');
                        // Set a timeout to re-enable the typeahead. 
                        setTimeout(oArgs.searchboxName + "Enabled=true", 3000);
                   } 
                );

                // Datasource.
                var ds = new YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource(oArgs.url);
                ds.connTimeout=5000;
                ds.responseType = YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource.TYPE_JSON; 
                ds.responseSchema = oArgs.requestSchema;
                ds.connXhrMode = 'cancelStaleRequests';
                ds.maxCacheEntries =  oArgs.maxCacheEntries ? oArgs.maxCacheEntries : 10; 
                ds.queryMatchSubset = oArgs.queryMatchSubset ? oArgs.queryMatchSubset : false;


                // Create and configure the control.
                var autocomplete = new YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete(oArgs.searchboxName, oArgs.suggestionsDivName, ds);


                // Only the item of interest should be returned 
                // (and thus appended to the url).
                autocomplete.generateRequest = function(sQuery) {
                    return sQuery; 
                };

                autocomplete.forceSelection =  oArgs.forceSelection ? true : false; 
                autocomplete.maxResultsDisplayed = oArgs.maxResults ? oArgs.maxResults : 5;
                autocomplete.minQueryLength = oArgs.minQueryLength ? oArgs.minQueryLength : 2;
                autocomplete.queryDelay = oArgs.queryDelay ? oArgs.queryDelay :0.2;
                autocomplete.typeAheadDelay = autocomplete.queryDelay + 0.1;
                autocomplete.typeAhead=true;
                if (oArgs.header) {
                    autocomplete.setHeader(oArgs.header);
                }
                if (oArgs.body) {
                    autocomplete.setBody(oArgs.body);
                }
                if (oArgs.footer) {
                    autocomplete.setFooter(oArgs.footer);
                }

                autocomplete.animVert = oArgs.animVert ? oArgs.animVert : true;
                autocomplete.animHoriz = oArgs.animHoriz ? oArgs.animHoriz :false;
                autocomplete.animSpeed = oArgs.animSpeed ? oArgs.animSpeed : 0.05;
                autocomplete.autoHighlight = oArgs.autoHighlight ? oArgs.autoHighlight : false;
                // Disable the browser's built-in autocomplete caching mechanism
                autocomplete.allowBrowserAutocomplete = false;
                autocomplete.prehighlightClassName = "yui-ac-prehighlight"; 

                autocomplete.resultTypeList = false; 
                autocomplete.formatResult = oArgs.formatResultFunction;

                // Block suggestion expansion of any in-progress requests.  
                autocomplete.doBeforeLoadData = function(oResultData, sQuery, sResultMatch) {
                    return !autocompleteIsDisbabled();      
                };

                if (!autocomplete.forceSelection) {
                    // Hook the ENTER key to disable the autocomplete and execute the callback. 
                    function checkReturn(e) {
                       var keyno = YAHOO.util.Event.getCharCode(e);
                       if (!autocompleteIsDisbabled() && keyno == 13) {
                            // Disable autocomplete.
                            eval(oArgs.searchboxName + 'Enabled' + '=false;');
                            // Set a timeout to reenable the typeahead. 
                            setTimeout(oArgs.searchboxName + "Enabled=true", 3000);
                            return eval(oArgs.callbackFunction + "('" + oArgs.searchboxName + "')");
                       }
                    }
                    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(autocomplete.getInputEl(), "keypress", checkReturn);
                }

                // Hook item selection to populate hidden fields and disable the autocomplete and execute the callback. 
                if (oArgs.itemSelectEventFunction) {
                try {
                  autocomplete.itemSelectEvent.subscribe(oArgs.itemSelectEventFunction);
                } catch (excep) { }
                }else{
                // Hook item selection to disable the autocomplete and execute the callback.    
                try {
                  autocomplete.itemSelectEvent.subscribe(function( oSelf , elItem , oData ) {  
                    // Disable autocomplete.
                    eval(oArgs.searchboxName + 'Enabled' + '=false;');

                    // Set a timeout to re-enable the typeahead. 
                    setTimeout(oArgs.searchboxName + "Enabled=true", 3000);

                    // Execute the callback.
                    eval(oArgs.callbackFunction + "('" + oArgs.searchboxName + "')");
                  });
                } catch (excep) { }
                }
            }

                function changeSearchView(viewId,isTabChange) {
                        //var arr = viewIdbaseUrl.split("|");
                        //var viewId = arr[0];
                        //var baseUrl = arr[1];
                        //TODO: Handle Browse URL redirection here based on the viewId

                        //Based on the viewId - determine the baseUrl - This is defined in main-nav.ftl
                        if(viewId == 2){
                            baseUrl = researchUrl;
                        }else if(viewId == 12){
                            baseUrl = analystUrl;
                        }
                        var keywords = document.getElementById("keywords").value
                        //Allow null keywords
                        var url = baseUrl + '?keywords=' + encodeURIComponent(keywords);            
                        if(isTabChange) {
                           url += '&tabChg=true';
                        }
                        window.location = url;  
                }

                function showSearchHistory() {
                    var keywords = document.getElementById("keywords").value
                    if(isEmptyKeyword(keywords)){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: searchhistoryurl,
                            success: function(htmlVal) {
                                document.getElementById("divSearchHistoryResults").innerHTML = htmlVal;
                            }
                        });
                    }
               }

               function submitSearchHistory(searchterm) {
                    document.getElementById("keywords").value = searchterm;
                    submitSearch('gSearchForm','');
                    return false;
               }
```

Comment: Where have you defined `success()`?

Comment: it's an anonymous function passed as the second argument to `getScript`, I think.  `getScript('/imagesrv/apps/common/js/jq/jquery-1.8.3.min.js', function() { //...`

Comment: Is it necessary to post all of your code here? Can you only post the relevant code blocks?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get around your error by throwing in a `typeof` conditional block.

I'm guessing somewhere in your code you're only passing 1 parameter to `getScript` when it actually requires 2.

I put together a minified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/zczqxse9/) to illustrate the issue.

The key things to take away is the `typeof`:

```
if (typeof (success) === "function") {
    success();
}
```

And the number of params being passed to your `getScript` function.

```
getScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js", test);
```

If you want to recreate your error, just remove `test` from the `getScript` function call and delete the `typeof` check.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks so much!